# Embeding Weather Underground

Tags: html, flash

Trying at the moment to embed this webcam from Weather Underground:

https://www.wunderground.com/webcams/Kehlegg/1/video.html?month=01&year=2018&filename=current.mp4

The following code is on the website:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
<object width="640" height="480" id="undefined" name="undefined" data="https://www.wunderground.com//icons.wunderground.com/swf/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.8.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="movie" value="https://www.wunderground.com//icons.wunderground.com/swf/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.8.swf" />
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<param name="flashvars" value='config={"key":"#@8d339434b223613a374","clip":{"autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true},"playlist":[{"url":"https://www.wunderground.com//icons.wunderground.com/webcamramdisk/k/e/Kehlegg/1/current.jpg?e%3D1514817767","autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true},{"url":"https://www.wunderground.com//icons.wunderground.com/webcamcurrent/k/e/Kehlegg/1/current.mp4?e%3D1514817767","autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true}],"plugins":{"controls":{"all":true,"mute":true,"play":true}}}' />
</object>
<p>
<a href="/webcams/Kehlegg/1/video.html">Kehlegg's Video Archive</a>
&mdash; <a href="/webcams/">Weather Underground Webcams</a>
</p>
</div>
```

Tried to use it but didnt work.